# How can I network 12.04 server and 12.04 desktop with the following setup

Tags: 12.04, server, lan

I have a desktop with 2 lan cards and a laptop with 1 lan card.

I want to connect the laptop to the desktop, so the desktop can share resources. The desktop will be running Ubuntu 12.04 server for serving ftp files. I am trying to setup a file server.

Neither computer needs to be connected to the internet. Once I have this setup, I will ask another question on how to add internet. However, I would like this to be a straight connection, so I'm not using a router. If I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have wpa_supplicant installed on the server?  If so, have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

It helped me to configure a wireless adapter on ubuntu 13.10 server edition.